# how to display background-color only on selected option in quiz

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors, logic, ng-class

In my ***[Angular quiz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app)***, I had the same logic: `option.selected && option.correct` and `option.selected && !option.correct` in both of my question component (*MultipleAnswerComponent* and *SingleAnswerComponent*) templates, so I moved out the logic and added two variables to the *QuizService* to share/reduce the duplicate code:

```
setOptions(optionSelected: boolean, optionCorrect: boolean): void {
  this.isCorrectOption = optionSelected && optionCorrect;
  this.isIncorrectOption = optionSelected && !optionCorrect;
}
```

And I also replaced the logic with the variables in the class binding like so: `[class.is-correct]="isCorrectOption"` and `[class.is-incorrect]="isIncorrectOption"`, but was getting red on all of the options, so I changed the background-color on the mat-checkbox/mat-radio-button to $light-gray !important and now it's gray. When I click on an option, the green or red background does not appear as expected.

**EDIT:** I am getting correct values for *isCorrectOption* and *isIncorrectOption* in QuizService and the values are passed back to the components. However now *ALL* of the options are displaying green/red when clicking on an option; I only need just the ***selected option*** to have a background-color. Not sure if *isCorrectOption* and *isIncorrectOption* are binding correctly to the class binding or if the logic that I'm using is incorrect...

I tried following the advice in the answer below, but was getting an error: couldn't read 'selected' of undefined. My current solution is pretty close to figuring it out but I still need some additional help to get the individual highlighting working properly. Please can you see my StackBlitz and help me to resolve this issue. Thank you.

in *MultipleAnswerComponent*/*SingleAnswerComponent* template:

```
<div class="options" *ngFor="let option of currentQuestion.options; index as i">
  <div *ngIf="multipleAnswer" or *ngIf="!multipleAnswer">
    <mat-checkbox or <mat-radio-button
      (change)="setSelected(i)"
      [class.is-correct]="isCorrectOption"
      [class.is-incorrect]="isIncorrectOption">
```

in MultipleAnswer/SingleAnswer TypeScript files:

```
setSelected(optionIndex: number): void {
  this.quizStarted = true;
  this.isCorrectAnswerSelected = this.isCorrect(this.currentQuestion.options[optionIndex].correct, optionIndex);
  this.answer.emit(optionIndex);

  if (this.correctAnswers.length === 1) {
    this.currentQuestion.options.forEach((option: Option) => option.selected = false);
  }
  this.currentQuestion.options[optionIndex].selected = true;

  if (
    optionIndex >= 0 &&
    this.currentQuestion &&
    this.currentQuestion.options &&
    this.currentQuestion.options[optionIndex]["correct"]
  ) {
    optionIndex = null;
    this.optionCorrect = true;
    this.timerService.stopTimer();
    this.quizService.correctSound.play();   
  } else {
    this.optionCorrect = false;
    this.quizService.incorrectSound.play();
  }

  this.quizService.setOptions(true, this.optionCorrect);
  this.isCorrectOption = this.quizService.isCorrectOption;
  this.isIncorrectOption = this.quizService.isIncorrectOption;
  this.alreadyAnswered = true;
}
```

Comment: Please use --background-color: $light-gray !important;

Comment: I am using background-color: $light-gray !important, the problem is that the is-correct and is-incorrect are not changing color when an answer is clicked correct/incorrect.

Comment: May be the root var has the colour red that's why it's not changing. I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: The background color of the option should change from gray to green or gray to red for each individual option depending if it is correct/incorrect. I don't think the logic is executing...

Comment: I figured out how to pass the values. Added console.log in the MultipleAnswerComponent and SingleAnswerComponent and am getting optionSelected: 'true' and optionCorrect: 'true' values for the correct answers and optionSelected: 'true' and optionCorrect: 'undefined' for incorrect answers, and am getting the same values from the QuizService. Close to figure this out and still need help to get the background colors to change. Please see my Stackblitz.

Comment: But still seem to get undefined values for isCorrectOptions and isIncorrectOptions in the QuizService and for the values I get through DI.

Comment: I hardcoded the values for optionSelected and optionCorrect and am getting the correct boolean values, but isCorrectOption and isIncorrectOption are still undefined in the quiz service.

Comment: I'm getting true values for isCorrectOption and isIncorrectOption before I click on an option because I initialized the optionSelected and optionCorrect to true, but when I click on the options the color doesn't change. And the values don't change when I click on an incorrect option.

Comment: I'm getting correct values for isCorrectOption and isIncorrectOption in the QuizService and the values are being passed back to the MultipleAnswerComponent/SingleAnswerComponent, just having trouble with getting the background colors to show on the options. Please could you help. Thank you!

Comment: The background colors seem to be highlighting on ALL of the options, but I need only the selected option(s) to be highlighted. Please can you help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is when you save the selected state in quiz service.

When you select one item in the quiz and call `setOptions(optionSelected: boolean, optionCorrect: boolean)`, the value of `optionSelected` is true (because of the current item). The problem is that the values of quiz service `isCorrectOption` and `isIncorrectOption` use the same instance of `optionSelected`, so it will be true for all items.

What to do?
Well, instead of using quiz service for this, use saved selected state in each Option instance.

In typescript you already do:

```js
this.optionSelected = this.currentQuestion.options[optionIndex];
this.optionSelected.selected = true;
this.optionSelected.correct = false;
```

So use these values in the html:

```html
[class.is-correct]="option.selected && option.correct"
```

(or create a function for this)

Of course, you can refactor this to use the quiz service fixing that issue.

Comment: I updated my TS file as shown above in stackblitz for the multiple-answer question. It doesn't seem to work, not sure what to replace in the class binding. I was hoping that I can simplify the logic down to a single variable like I had before with isCorrectOption and isIncorrectOption.

Comment: @adrisons is correct and the solution is working as you can see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app-kuenol?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fquestion%2Fmultiple-answer%2Fmultiple-answer.component.html the alternative would be to set the classname for each option and the bind to that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app-kshcwt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fquestion%2Fmultiple-answer%2Fmultiple-answer.component.ts

Comment: Yes, the second Stackblitz is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`isCorrectOption` and `isIncorrectOption` both are (not empty) strings and therefor evaluates as truthy.

Change your code to this and you should be fine:

```
isCorrectOption = option.selected && option.correct;
isIncorrectOption = option.selected && !option.correct;
```

Comment: I created this.option = this.currentQuestion.options[optionIndex]; and passed this to the QuizService, but getting an error: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined." Please could you see my Stackblitz.

Comment: I figured out how to pass the values. Added console.log in the MultipleAnswerComponent and SingleAnswerComponent and am getting optionSelected: 'true' and optionCorrect: 'true' values for the correct answers and optionSelected: 'true' and optionCorrect: 'undefined' for incorrect answers, and am getting the same values from the QuizService. Close to figure this out and still need help to get the background colors to change. Please see my Stackblitz.

Comment: I'm getting undefined values for isCorrectOptions and isIncorrectOptions in the QuizService and for the values I get through DI.

Comment: ok I hardcoded the values for optionSelected and optionCorrect and am getting the correct true/false values, but isCorrectOption and isIncorrectOption are still undefined

Comment: I'm getting true values for isCorrectOption and isIncorrectOption because I initialized the optionSelected and optionCorrect to true, but when I click on the options the color doesn't change. The values don't change when I click on an option.

Comment: The background colors are highlighting on ALL of the options, but I need only the selected option(s) to be highlighted. Please can you help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to highlight selected options, you do not need to apply `is-correct` and `is-incorrect` classes to radio button.

Instead you can add new class `selected` and use it like:

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="setSelected(i)" [class.selected]="option.selected">
  ...
</mat-checkbox>
```

and

```
<mat-radio-button (change)="setSelected(i)" [class.selected]="option.selected">
  ...
</mat-radio-button>
```

Add .selected class to respective css files:

```
.selected {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

take a look at updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app-p7kzio).

Comment: Actually I do need those classes because I need to highlight correct answers a green background and incorrect answers a red background. I was using a variable like isCorrectOption and isIncorrectOption because I have the same logic in both MultipleAnswerComponent and SingleAnswerComponent and hoping to reduce the logic to a single variable.

Comment: @mjbk123 but I believe your binding is totally wrong, it is not even considering current option. So what kind of highlighting you exactly need? corret/incorrect only for selected ones?

Comment: Yes I need individual correct/incorrect - a correct answer should be highlighted green and an incorrect answer should be highlighted red. And the logic should be simplified: [class.is-correct] = "isCorrectOption", not option.selected && option.correct

Comment: @mjbk123 but if I make any change it will looks like something you had before refactoring. I don't understand what do you mean by avoid duplication. You still need to store isSelected and isCorrect on option it self.

Comment: The logic in the template should be as simple as possible. I moved the code into the service to share the duplicate code because it was the same in both component files.  The code in the component uses dependency injection to send the values back to the component from the service. This should be possible.

Comment: @mjbk123 but even if you want to share it in service, you need dictionary. You cannot just have single variable to store state of n number of options.

Comment: Yes using a dictionary makes sense if I can share the logic in the service and have a simplified logic in the template. Could you show a solution that uses dictionary to highlight the correct/incorrect answers individually?

Answer (score 1):

Check the below line of code to be corrected in

> multiple-answer.component.html

from:

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="setSelected(i)" [class]="option.className">
```

to:

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="setSelected(i)" [class.is-correct]="option.selected && option.correct" [class.is-incorrect]="option.selected && !option.correct">
```